# Combobox in a cell of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I have a database with Table name “tblProducts” with columns header “ProductCode, Descriptions, UnitPirce, Quantity, TotalPrice”

I have a DataGrid in my WPF form, and manually create the column headers as below:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridOrderedProducts" Margin="10,10,10,0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="180" BorderThickness="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Code" MinWidth="120" FontSize="11"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descriptions" MinWidth="200" FontSize="11"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Unit Price" MinWidth="100" FontSize="11"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" MinWidth="100" FontSize="11"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" MinWidth="100" FontSize="11"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I want to have a ComboBox in a cell under “Product Code” columns so that users can select a product and query all the related data from that ProductCode.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two- ways,

(i).By using [`DataGridComboboxColom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="100" x:Name="cmbProduct" SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Code, Mode=TwoWay}" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding Code}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

(ii)By using [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx)

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ProductCode">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Code}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Codes}"></ComboBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```